# Copyright string search and replace issue

Tags: python, regex

How to write regex for matching a string `Copyright (C) 2017 - 2018,`

Here is my code,

```
import re
find = 2018
COPYRIGHT_PATTERN = re.compile(
    r'Copyright (C) \d{4} - {0},'.format(find)
)

test_str = 'Copyright (C) 2002 - 2018,'
if COPYRIGHT_PATTERN.match(test_str):
    print('Found match')
```

But it is not working. I also want to replace `2018` with `2019`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may fix the current code like this:

```
import re
find = 2018
COPYRIGHT_PATTERN = re.compile(
    r'(Copyright \(C\) \d{{4}} - ){0},'.format(find)
)

test_str = 'Copyright (C) 2002 - 2018,'
print(COPYRIGHT_PATTERN.sub(r'\g<1>2019', test_str))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xHq6ZR)

**Details**

- In a formatted string, literal `{` and `}` must be doubled.
- The `(` and `)` chars must be escaped in a regex to match literal parentheses
- If you want to replace, use `re.sub` and not `re.match`
- To match and keep a part of a match use a capturing group (see the unescaped parentheses I added at the start and before `{0}`)
- To replace with a backreference and a digit right after it is recommended to use unambiguous backreferences, `\g<X>`

Comment: Thank you so much :), I thought prepending `r` with string is enough & I don't have to escape anything.

Comment: @n33rma Even in that case you should have had doubts if `\d{4}` would work - if you thought that `r` would escape the string, all patterns would be turned into literals, right? However, all `r` does is turns off the string escape sequence support and does not do all proper escaping for the regex engine for yourself.

Comment: Oh okay, Thank you

Comment: Is there any change I can make 2019 configurable via format?
COPYRIGHT_PATTERN.sub(r'\g<1>{0}'.format(replace), test_str)) I tried and it is not working.